# Missing filled contours when using contourf

Tags: python, matplotlib, contourf

I am trying to plot plot a function over a 2D domain using [`contourf`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contourf.html). Unfortunately, my first attempt did not work out very well. There was a region in the plot that was unexpectedly not covered by any contours. For debugging purposes, I have reduced the problem to the smallest dataset that I could find that also reveals the issue with missing filled contours:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

v = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
x, y = np.meshgrid(v, v)

z = np.array([[5.5e-14, 5.5e-14, 5.5e-14, 5.5e-14],
              [2e-13, 2e-13, 2e-13, 2e-13],
              [2.2e-13, 2.2e-13, 2.2e-13, 2.2e-13],
              [0, 0,0, 0]])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
cntr = ax.contourf(x, y, z)
fig.colorbar(cntr, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

This gives the following plot:

[image]

as you can see there are missing contours from `y = 1.5` to approximately `y=2.0`.

Another strange thing I observed: If I normalize the `z` matrix by multiplying by e.g. `1e14` before plotting it works fine.

Comment: This seems to be a bug, which is still present in the current development version. Would you like to open an issue about it [on the GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues)?

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice, I have submitted an issue at the Matplotlib GitHub issue tracker: [Missing filled contours when using contourf](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/11587)

Comment: It works also if you use `cntr = ax.contourf(x, y, z, extend='max')`.